# Point To Point Link when connected into the main switch

Tags: networking

I have two geographically separated DC and DR site with hosts on the same subnet. Hosts on respective networks is connected with each other through respective switches at each site. Both the switches are GigaBit switches. I have a point to point link between the locations which is 5MBPS.

When I connect the networks with the point to point link, I get a ping latency of about 18 ms. However as soon as clients start accessing the DC, through a WAN link on a router in front of the switch, I experience serious degradation of connectivity (ping latency = 400 ms and 50% drops).

Could someone please tell me, what do I need to do, to alleviate the problem?

Any help, much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, are the clients accessing the DC through a different connection? Are they accessing the DC through the point to point link or not?

Comment: No. The clients access the DC through a WAN link terminated on a router in DC and not through the point to point link. Point to point link is only (supposedly) for hosts from DC and DR interconnecting between each other.